# Can I do this? $A^c - B^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If not how can I work with it? (A and B are sets)

$A^c - B^c$

I am trying to simlify the above...

$= (B-A) - (A-B) $

$= 2B - 2A $

$= B-A$

Is it safe to say that $A^c = B - A$? Furthermore is my logic correct?

Comment: A and B are sets?

Comment: Yes they are, sorry

Comment: There are many ways to write expressions equivalent to $A^c\setminus B^c$. A simple version is $A^c\cap B$.

Answer (score 4):

$A^C-B^C=A^C\cap (B^C)^C=A^C\cap B=B\cap A^C=B-A.$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align} x \in A^c - B^c & \iff x \notin A \land x\notin (B^c) \\ \\ & \iff x\notin A \land \lnot(x\notin B) \\ \\ & \iff x \notin A \land x \in B \\ \\ &\iff x \in B - A\end{align}$$

$$\therefore A^c - B^c = B - A$$

---

So yes, it is certainly "safe" and indeed correct, to say that $ A^c - B^c = B - A$. However, your logic is not correct. You treated your sets just like variables, using multiplication as we do on real numbers. The problem is, $A$ and $B$ are sets, and $2B$ doesn't make sense here (or at best, you have not defined what you mean by $2B$). Exactly how do you define $2\times \text{a set}?$ For that matter, how do you define $B + B$?

In any case, $A^c \not\equiv B - A$.

$A^c$ means **all** elements *not in* $A$, not just the elements that are in $B$ but not in $A$. So the set-minus operation on sets is not usually equivalent to taking the complement of a set.

Comment: Nice and clean +1